# Run play framework app at specified socket

Tags: sockets, nginx, playframework

Play documentation only describes changing the default 9000 port to some other by `-Dhttp.port <port>` argument.

Is it possible to use unix socket instead of port? Due to administrator's policy every application has to provide socket which is then used by nginx used as front end web server.

I've found a [chapter in play docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/HTTPServer) about using nginx but again - it only covers app running at port.

I'm using play 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for listening to unix sockets in Netty which Play uses as http server. There is a third party library for Netty but you will probably not be able to plug it into Play without some serious messing around with the framework internals.

https://github.com/Flipkart/phantom/wiki/Unix-domain-socket-transport-for-netty